# Microsoft Academic Graph CalcHisotgram Being Aborted

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, academic-graph

I'm using the CalcHistogram endpoint to query the total number of paper entities for every year from around 1980 to 2018. A typical response looks like this:

```
{
  "expr": "Y=2001",
  "num_entities": 4179575,
  "histograms": []
}
```

That's `4179575` papers from the year `2001`.

However, starting at around year `2002` (the exact year is not consistent), the return values are being aborted.

```
{
  "expr": "Y=2002",
  "histograms": [],
  "aborted": true
}
```

This is what my request looks like. I've tried using both `GET` and `POST` methods.

```
GET 
https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/calchistogram? expr=Y=2002&model=latest&count=10&offset=0 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com
```

Any ideas on why this is being aborted or how I can find the total number of papers for each year?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that CalcHistogram endpoint also accepts a `timeout` parameter. The api will try to evaluate the query until timeout (which defaults to 1000 milli) is reached, at which point it returns `aborted: true`.

So, just add `timeout: 5000` to your request.